# Is there a way to style infopath forms in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, infopath, css

I want to know if it is possible to apply styling from a custom css stylesheet to infopath forms in SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. You can apply some styling in InfoPath Designer, but that's about it. The rendered InfoPath form will have automatically generated ids with variable numbers, so it's pretty hard to track down with regular CSS.

If you want to go into that direction, you may want to look into jQuery, but getting that to work inside an InfoPath form is another challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Is's not easy, but one option is there. Rename Infopath form template with .cab extension. There are so many files in .cab folder. Extract all files in one folder. Open your view file (ex. View1.xsl) and add custom css. Reconvert folder to .cab file using cmd command. Rename .cab to .xsn file.